# Need a help about numbering and refering an Appendix

Tags: sectioning, appendices

I have 6 sections in a paper, after that I wish to write Appendix A and Appendix B. In section 4, I wish to refer Appendix A as well as Appendix B somewhere. But it is showing $6$ instead of Appendix A. Please help.

Comment: Welcome. `:-)` This problem is potentially complex and requires actual code reproducing the problem to understand where it's going wrong. Try to make a minimal example, which reproduces the problem. This should be a document which *can* compile, but does not produce the intended result (in your case `Appendix A` as desired output and `6` as current output).

Comment: @1010011010: Please look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks, where you can look up `stock comments`, you may of course your own `;-)`

Comment: @user45567: Welcome to TeX.SX

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm aware of those. Thanks anyway. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}%



\begin{document}

\section{First}
\blindtext
\section{Second}
\blindtext

\section{Third}
\blindtext

\section{Fourth}
\blindtext

In Appendix \ref{appendixsection::1} we will see that..., however in
Appendix \ref{appendixsection::2} there is also shown that ...

\section{Fifth}
\blindtext

\section{Sixth}
\blindtext

\clearpage

\appendix
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}


\section{First of Appendix}\label{appendixsection::1}
\blindtext[1-20]
\section{Second of Appendix}\label{appendixsection::2}
\blindtext[21-40]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user45567: Happy `TeXing` ;-)

Comment: Only `\appendix` is enough since `\appendix` is defined as `\long macro:->\par \setcounter {section}{0}\setcounter {subsection}{0}\gdef \thesection {\@Alph \c@section }`.